# SQL Function- SUM must be declared

Tags: sql, plsql

I am creating the following function so when receiving an id, it will sum the weight of that user in the year 2021, and give an award if it gets above 200 or above 100 abd below 200:

```
create or replace FUNCTION calculapremio(id_funcionario NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
    premio NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN (SELECT SUM(peso) FROM funcionario_arvore WHERE id_funcionario = id_funcionario AND TO_CHAR(dataC,'yyyy') = 2021) LOOP
            IF i.SUM(peso) >= 200 THEN
                premio := 100;
            ELSIF i.SUM(peso) >= 100 AND i.SUM(peso) < 200 THEN
                premio := 50;
            ELSE
                premio := 0;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN premio;
    END;
```

However it says on the first IF statment that SUM must be declared. Someone cares to help me?

I also tried to asign to a variable ( SELECT SUM(peso) INTO v_total) and it also didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

you should alias the value to refer in the loop, i is the value of sum_peso, you dont have to explicitly  mention it

```
create or replace FUNCTION calculapremio(id_funcionario NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
    premio NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN (SELECT SUM(peso) as sum_peso FROM funcionario_arvore WHERE id_funcionario = id_funcionario AND TO_CHAR(dataC,'yyyy') = 2021) LOOP
            IF i >= 200 THEN
                premio := 100;
            ELSIF i >= 100 AND i < 200 THEN
                premio := 50;
            ELSE
                premio := 0;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN premio;
    END;
```